How to create a box shadow effect when overlaying an image on a video using FFmpeg?
I'm working on a video project where I need to overlay an image on a background video. I've managed to achieve the basic overlay using the following FFmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -i image_video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset veryfast output.mp4

This command overlays the image on the background video, centered. However, I would like to add an effect similar to a CSS box shadow, where the overlaid image has a shadow that gradually fades out, giving it a sense of depth.
I've tried various combinations of FFmpeg filters, such as boxblur, gblur, and drawbox, but I can't quite achieve the desired effect.
I'm attaching two images to illustrate what I have and what I'm trying to achieve:
The current result of my FFmpeg command : https://i.imgur.com/3uK79jP.png
An example of the desired box shadow effect : https://i.imgur.com/KaIq7VI.png

if resolution of image.png 312x420, create shadow +10px
ffmpeg -lavfi "
color=black:322x430,format=rgba,
geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='
if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-20)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-20),
if(lte(hypot(20-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),20-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),20),
lerp(0,255,(10-hypot(20-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),20-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))))/10),0),

if(lt(X,  20)*between(Y,20,H-20),lerp(0,255,   X /10),
if(gt(X,W-20)*between(Y,20,H-20),lerp(0,255,(W-X)/10),
if(lt(Y,  20)*between(X,20,W-20),lerp(0,255,   Y /10),
if(gt(Y,H-20)*between(X,20,W-20),lerp(0,255,(H-Y)/10),
0)))))'
" -frames 1 shadow.png

then overlay shadow (shifted to 3px down) and rounded image by 10px on background video
ffmpeg -i bg.mkv -i shadow.png -i image.png -lavfi "
[2]geq=lum='p(X,Y)':
a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-10)*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-10),
if(lte(hypot(10-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),10-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),10),255,0),255)'[p];
[0][1]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2+3[v];
[v][p]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2
" out.mp4

bash script:
#!/bin/bash

IMG="image.png"
IFS=, read WID HEI <<< $(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height -of csv=p=0 "$IMG")
echo $WID $HEI
# margin, change it:
LOW=10
(( RAD=2*$LOW ))
(( SHW=$WID+$LOW ))
(( SHH=$HEI+$LOW ))

ffmpeg -i bg.mkv -i "$IMG" -lavfi "
color=black:${SHW}x${SHH}:d=0.01,format=rgba,
geq=lum='p(X,Y)':a='
if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-${RAD})*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-${RAD}),
  if(lte(hypot(${RAD}-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),${RAD}-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),${RAD}),
  lerp(0,255,(${LOW}-hypot(${RAD}-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),${RAD}-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))))/${LOW}),0),
if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-${RAD})*between(Y,${RAD},H-${RAD}),lerp(0,255,(W/2-abs(W/2-X))/${LOW}),
if(gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-${RAD})*between(X,${RAD},W-${RAD}),lerp(0,255,(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))/${LOW}),
0)))'[s];

[1]geq=lum='p(X,Y)':
a='if(gt(abs(W/2-X),W/2-${LOW})*gt(abs(H/2-Y),H/2-${LOW}),
if(lte(hypot(${LOW}-(W/2-abs(W/2-X)),${LOW}-(H/2-abs(H/2-Y))),${LOW}),255,0),255)'[p];

[0][s]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2+${LOW}/3[v];
[v][p]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2
" out.mp4

ffplay out.mp4

